# Select from dual connect by level on Vertica db

Tags: sql, oracle, vertica

I'm new to Vertica db and i'm trying to translate SQL Oracle codes I was using im my previous job. Currently I'm trying to generate one column with values from 1 to 20 with step 1. In Oracle I used:

```
select rownum from dual connect by level <22
```

I've already checked that dual table exists in Vertica, but cennect by statement doesn't work. How can I write IT in Vertica?

Comment: Please check [`WITH Clause Recursion`](https://www.vertica.com/docs/10.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/AnalyzingData/Queries/Subqueries/WithClauseRecursion.htm) section of the docs

Answer (score 0):

A real waste of resources is this way:

```
ALTER SESSION SET PARAMETER WithClauseRecursionLimit=20;
WITH RECURSIVE seq AS (
  SELECT 1 AS i
  UNION ALL
  SELECT I + 1 FROM seq
)
SELECT * FROM seq;
```

But the much more effective method is a side effect of the `TIMESERIES` clause that we love so much at Vertica:

```
WITH limits(ts) AS (
  SELECT DATE '2000-01-01'::timestamp + 1 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT DATE '2000-01-01'::timestamp + 21
)
SELECT
  tm::DATE - DATE '2000-01-01' AS i
FROM limits
TIMESERIES tm AS '1 day' OVER(ORDER BY ts)
```